# SSRS reporting - Matrix report issue with row group and column group

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

This is the data I have.

```
Name       Date       Quarter   Sales
A        01/2021          1        1
B        01/2021          1        2
C        01/2021          1        3
A        03/2021          2        1
B        03/2021          2        2
C        03/2021          2        3
```

This is how I want it to display in SSRS

```
                Quarter 1      Quarter 2
                 01/2021        03/2021
                  Sales          Sales         Total Sales
Name     A          1               1              2
Name     B          2               2              4
Name     C          3               3              6
```

Please could anyone suggest how to achieve the layout needed in SSRS.

Comment: What's wrong with a Matrix then? Your title says there was an issue; what was that issue?

Comment: I have tried to do various row groups and column groups but data does not align so totals are off. I need suggestions on which fields to do rows or column groups to get the desired layout.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your row group is the name, and your column groups are Quarter, and then Date.

Comment: What about sales where does that go?

Comment: Not in the group by, that's a metric; it's the value your aggregating.

Comment: Okay let me try that. Thanks.